# cv2 no inicializa la cámara

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("visor",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord ("q"):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

no me deja iniciar la camara y no se como arreglarlo.

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TEMP.idea-PCgonzalez\Desktop\python(prueba#1)\krakent.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("visor",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: has verificado que tu webcam no esté en uso por otra aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

Yo también tuve un problema parecido pero lo resolví con el siguiente código. Te lo adjunto para que lo pruebes.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(3, 640) #DEFINIMOS EL WIDTH // CON EL PRIMER PARÁMERTRO IDENTIFICAMOS EL ID DE WIDTH
cap.set(4, 480) #DEFINIMOS EL HEIGTH // CON EL PRIMER PARÁMERTRO IDENTIFICAMOS EL ID DE HEIGHT

while True:
   sucess, img = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('Video', img)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'): 
      break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```